# stdin reaching EOF after first line

Tags: c, std, stdin, fgets, eof

I'm trying to pipe a file to my program using `type file.txt | myprogram.exe`. I'm reading it in with:

```
char *line;
struct block *newblock, *cur;
int i, osl, cbs, rs;
int startblock;

/* read in the blocks ... */
while (!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin)) {
    cbs = 2048;
    line = (char *)malloc(cbs + 1);
    if (!line) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    line[cbs] = '\0';

    /* read in the line */
    if (!fgets(line, cbs, stdin)) {
        free(line);
        continue;
    } else {
        while (line[cbs - 2]) {
            /* expand the line */
            line = (char *)realloc(line, (cbs * 2) + 1);
            if (!line) {
                perror("realloc");
                exit(1);
            }
            line[cbs * 2] = '\0';

            /* read more */
            if (!fgets(line + cbs - 1, cbs + 1, stdin))
                break;

            cbs *= 2;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But just after reading the first line, `feof()` returns true, even though there are multiple lines in the file. How can that happen?

Comment: Please take some time to read [Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: Looks like `while (line[cbs - 2])` can read the whole file in the inner loop, as it is checking what can be uninitialised memory.

Comment: As for your algorithm it seems totally wrong. If you want to read a line without knowing its exact length, then use `fgets` (like you're doing) but check if the string ends with a newline or not. If there's no newline at the end then there's more of the line to read. Use `strchr` or `strcspn` to find out if there's a newline at the end (of the string, which might not be the end of the array!).

Answer (score 1):

The code has multiple problems:

- the test for end of file is incorrect: `feof()` only provides meaningful information **after** a read function has failed.
- the reallocation scheme is broken: you test the second to last byte of the array, but `fgets()` may not have set this byte if the line is shorter.

Here is how you can fix your program:

- either use `getline()` if your system supports it. `getline()` allocates a large enough buffer to read a full line at a time.
- or use `fgets` to read a line fragment and check if it ends with a newline.